# Checking if Class respondsToSelector not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following line compiles fine but incorrectly returns false in iOS 8. Why?

```
[[NSLayoutConstraint class] respondsToSelector:@selector(setActive:)]
```

However, the following correctly returns true -

```
[self.heightLayoutConstraint respondsToSelector:@selector(setActive:)]
```

where `self.heightLayoutConstraint` is of type `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Comment: Because `setActive:` is not a class method.

Comment: Ah, makes sense! Then, how do I check if a particular class will respond to a selector if I don't have an instance of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setActive:` is not a class method on `NSLayoutConstraint`, so the return value is correct: the class itself does not respond to that selector.

I think you're looking for the class method [`+instancesRespondToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/instancesRespondToSelector:)

```
[NSLayoutConstraint instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setActive:)]
```